# Abnormal phenomenon for Comparable<T> in Java

Tags: java, comparable

When I write a `RankedObject` class which implements `Comparable<RankedObject>`:

```
public static class RankedObj implements Comparable<RankedObj>      {
    int i;
    public RankedObj(int i)     {
        this.i=i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RankedObj [i=" + i + "]";
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(RankedObj o) {
        if(this.i == 3)     {  // '3' will always be the smallest item
            return -1;
    }
    return this.i-o.i;
}
```

I want to make the list of RankedObject "in ascending order on the whole, at the same time, the number `3` to always be the `smallest` one". When testing, I found the order of the original list really affects the result, and the result is not correct in some cases. Namely:

```
//----CASE 1----
List<RankedObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new RankedObj(11));
list.add(new RankedObj(1));
list.add(new RankedObj(12));
list.add(new RankedObj(3));
list.add(new RankedObj(8));
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);

//output (as I intend)
[RankedObj [i=3], RankedObj [i=1], RankedObj [i=8], RankedObj [i=11], RankedObj [i=12]]

//----CASE 2----
List<RankedObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new RankedObj(11));
list.add(new RankedObj(12));
list.add(new RankedObj(3));
list.add(new RankedObj(8));
list.add(new RankedObj(1));
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);

//output (not what my Comparable intends)
[RankedObj [i=1], RankedObj [i=3], RankedObj [i=8], RankedObj [i=11], RankedObj [i=12]]
```

Could anyone tell my why? as well as how can I realize the purpose of making the list in ascending order on the whole while '3' being the smallest item? Thanks a lot!

**P.S.** According to my test using a `Comparator` in which the code is the same as the code in `Comparable`, the result is the same:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<RankedObj>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(RankedObj o1, RankedObj o2) {
        if(o1.i == 3)       {
            return -1;
    }
    return o1.i-o2.i;
    }
});
```

Comment: You want ID 3 to be first, followed by ascending IDs from 1 to infinity? Basically, you want to sort an array so that ID3 is first and then the rest of the array is **sorted** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison isn't symmetric.

Consider these two calls:

```
RankedObj x = new RankedObj(1);
RankedObj y = new RankedObj(3);
System.out.println(x.compareTo(y)); // -2
System.out.println(y.compareTo(x)); // -1
```

They *should* both give an answer of 0, or give answers with opposite signs. Instead, they'll both return a negative value - because in the first call, `o1.i` is 1 (not 3) so it will fall back to `o1.i - o2.i` - which is still negative.

Additionally, you have a problem that if you have a very strongly negative value, when you subtract a strongly positive value from it, the subtraction will overflow.

You need to fix it to be symmetric *and* to avoid overflow. This should do it:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(RankedObj o) {
    // Handle equality first
    if (this.i == o.i) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Handle the magic value correctly on *both* sides
    if(this.i == 3) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (o.i == 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Fall back to normal comparsions
    return Integer.compare(i, o.i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@Override
public int compare(RankedObj o1, RankedObj o2) {
    if(o1.i == o2.i){       {
        return 0;
    } else if(o1.i == 3)       {
        return -1;
    } else if (o2.i == 3){
        return 1;
    }
return o1.i-o2.i;
}
```

The implemenation assumes you're only using small numbers which don't result in an overflow when subtracting one value from the other.